# Is there a way to display custom text for TextProperty? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx-8, scenebuilder, tornadofx

Let's assume that I have a TextField and a Label

```
TextField customTextField
Label customLabel
```

I want to bind the `customLabel` to the `customTextField`'s TextProperty. After doing so the `customLabel` will be updated according to what the `customTextField` contains. However,  I want something a bit more than this. For example, if I enter the amount `15.0` I want it to update the `customLabel`'s text to `15.0/100.0`. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into string bindings

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. I appreciate it.